# If I use Google authentication for a site, can I tell if the user has 2 step auth?

Tags: security, authentication, google-authentication

I want to use Google authentication for a site, but want to enforce use of Google 2 step authentication.  Is there a way for me to tell if a user has this on or not?  I want to boot users who don't use it.

Note that this is for a non-Google site, so I can't use the enforcement capability that Google Apps allows for.